# Write to log when new user is created

Tags: postgresql

I played with Postgres' EVENT TRIGGER to catch and log when a new user is created in my system.  However, I was able to catch many other ddl actions but the creation of new user it failed to catch.  Is it possible to catch the creation of new user with a event trigger.  If not, what is the best way to catch and log when new user is added to the system

Thanks
Avi

Comment: According to [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-matrix.html) there is (currently) no event fired for `create user` or `create role`

Comment: you can created a job to view pg_user, pg_roles catalogs and check for new users, but these do not have created date/time.